# How can I embed a Rich Text Area using JQuery in my Web Page?

Tags: jquery

I need to add a simple Rich Text Area into my project using JQuery. I need only the basic functionality such as so as to provide user most of the editing features. Can someone suggest one of the available plugin and the way in which its used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current project uses TinyMCE

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php

Click View Source: (extract)

```
<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.3");
</script>

<!-- Load jQuery build -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
                $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
                        // Location of TinyMCE script
                        script_url : '../js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', 
                });
        });
</script>
```